# disadvantage of using php's mysqli library over mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

hello I have an assignment that asking me to give at least one disadvantage of using php's MySQLi library over php's MySQL .. I don't see any .. can any one give me some disadvantage because I can never find one

Comment: mysql doesn't even exist in php 7, so I'd say whoever gave you that assignment needs to get up-to-date.

Comment: let's say that the assignment never mentioned that this question in php 7 so .. may you please help me?

Comment: Could the simple answer possibly be "none" ?

Comment: OK, so maybe mysql is better for job security, since eventually all php libraries that support it will be end-of-lifed, and someone will have to go in and fix it. Billable hours!

Comment: One extra character to type.

Answer (score 0):

1. MySQLi has this feature called prepared statements which is nothing but a safer way of sending data to MySQL and protecting yourself from getting hacked using SQL injection. This is the foremost reason why one should always prefer MySQLi over MySQL.
2. MySQLi extension has been specifically developed to take advantage of the new features available in MySQL Server version 4.1.3 and above. So the thing is if you still use the MySQL extension then you might not be able to take full advantage of the new MySQL server features.
3. MySQLi is object orientated and a lot has already been talked about how useful Object Oriented programming is.
4. MySQLi supports multiple Statements, Complex Transaction statements and has enhanced debugging capabilities and embedded server support.